# Can't git revert to older commit right after clone (no changes made)

Tags: git-clone

I need to test an older version (commit) of some code from github. I made git clone and then

```
git revert $id
```

where &id was id of the version that i need to check. I got this error:

```
error: could not revert 9a0d90d... Version 1.2.1
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
```

I made no changes to any files after clone.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you any to test an older version, you should create a branch directly from your older id

```
git checkout -b test $id
```

[`git revert`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-revert.html) tries to compute a new commit which would cancel changes introduced since `$id`. Conflicts can occurs when computing the negative merge.
You don't need that for consulting/testing an older revision.
And if you need to make any changes in the context of that test, you will already be in a '`test`' branch.